# AWS Client VPN Endpoint to private subnet timing out

Tags: amazon-web-services

We have an RDS cluster in a private subnet. I am trying to establish connection to it via VPN.

I followed the instructions here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpn/latest/clientvpn-admin/cvpn-getting-started.html#cvpn-getting-started-endpoint
to set up a AWS client vpn connection.

To recap, I:

1. Created client and server keys
2. Added keys to ACM
3. Created a VPN connection
4. Added subnet associations and an "allow all" authorization rule

I am able to connect to the VPN successfully. However, when I attempt to connect to the RDS cluster, the connection times out.

What am I missing?